# Allow more [featured] posts in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community-bulletin, sidebar, featured-questions

There are only a few slots for featured posts in the sidebar, especially when there are a couple blog posts and a few MSE featured posts.  Now that we aren't taking room for hot meta posts, can we utilize some of that room for more manually selected featured posts?

**Can we add more slots for featured posts in the sidebar?**

> I'm thinking 6 to 8 ... – rene

To be clear, I'm suggesting that the limit be increased to be more than three, *even if the meta.SE featured posts exist* and there are a few blog/MSE posts.  You could simply have a static max-6 Stack Overflow featured posts, regardless of how many MSE and Blog posts there were, for example.

---

<sub>Related: [Why is an important Meta post tagged [featured] not showing in "Featured on Meta"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388321/why-is-an-important-meta-post-tagged-featured-not-showing-in-featured-on-meta)</sub>

Comment: If increasing the number of posts that show up is not an option, then can you make it so that the **Featured on Meta** section cycles through the posts which have the `featured` tag periodically.

Comment: Thanks.  That might be a separate request to make it update slightly faster.  Maybe.  I'm suggesting that the limit be increased **even if the meta.SE featured posts exist.**  Maybe not 5?  I just threw that out there.  But more than just two, even if there are a few blog/MSE posts.

Comment: I'm thinking 6 to 8 ...

Answer (score 7):

I wavered between calling this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for a bit because, technically, it is the case that you have six slots... but that seems to ignore the request for *more* slots, which I'm declining.

Since 2020 (at least) y'all have had six slots. Those slots can include:

- Blog posts (max 2)
- Current election (max 1, not inclusive of any featured posts about the election)
- Featured MSO posts
- "Hot" MSO posts
- Site events (unused since 2016)

It does not include MSE featured posts. Those get up to two slots of their own and are configured separately, increasing the total maximum number of items in the bulletin to 8. As to hot posts, the system will fill any available slots that aren't taken up with featured and blog posts.

I do understand, with the Ask Wizard and Staging Ground that we're asking for a lot of space and that's clashing with the renewed work on tag burninations. I manage the process for featuring posts on MSE and MSO and I have a Jira board with all of the upcoming posts that we're planning to make here that we'd like to be featured.

Usually we don't have anything for MSO at all, so we're in a bit of an odd space with the higher volume. What I can say is that, since the CMs manage the process, we also control the rate that posts get sent here and we work to limit the number we ask the mods to feature on MSO to two at a time. This leaves at least two slots for other things.

I can also work internally to see if we can try to only request one slot at a time so that y'all have a bit more space for other discussions.

### OK, but why can't we have [more]?

My major concern here is in overloading the bulletin with too much content. The more stuff that's in that section, the more it turns into a block of text and the more likely people are to zone it out and not read it. When it's full, it's already a lot and having two more slots will exacerbate it.

I know that there's lots of great things going on here - and I'm glad to see it! Tag management in particular is often annoying but really important - so kudos to you for working on that. But I think having more slots will be counter productive to this.

Comment: At some point of time, someone said that there could be [no more than 2 featured posts shown on the community bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/213575). That was wrong, but still made sense. Right now I hope that at we are guaranteed at least 1 hot post.

Comment: I don't think the original request was referring to the entire banner... 'featured posts' has always been a specific section within that. We still only seem to have two there. Given an option, I would rather do away with the blog post (or at least relegate it to the latest blog post only), and show more featured or hot Meta posts.

Comment: @TylerH y'all can have up to 6 if there's no blog posts. With the blog, you can have four. I think that post Shog wrote (that Braiam linked) says something about not showing a single hot post so if there's three featured, y'all will actually get 7 slots.

Comment: @Braiam The number of hot posts will depend on the number of MSO featured posts and blog posts. Assuming two blog posts, as long as there are fewer than four featured MSO posts, there should be at least two Hot Meta Posts, as far as I can tell (also excluding oddball things like events and elections).

Comment: I'd deduct the blog posts from the number of slots that we get, because, well, we don't get them. But all in all, good explanation.