# Why is an important Meta post tagged [featured] not showing in "Featured on Meta"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, featured-questions

Today Shog9 made an important Meta post:

**[Experiment: closing and reopening happens at 3 votes for the next 30 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388313/3744182)**

And (correctly, IMHO) tagged it as [[featured]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured), one of two currently so tagged:

- *[Experiment: closing and reopening happens at 3 votes for the next 30 days](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-days)* (asked 3 hours ago as of asking this question).
- *[Should we burninate the [sales] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385971/should-we-burninate-the-sales-tag)* (asked asked Jun 11 at 20:17).

However, it's not showing up in my "Featured on Meta" pane.

Here's what I see when logged in:

[image: Screenshot when logged in]

And here's what I see when browsing in a different browser, with cookies blocked:

[image]

In neither case is the post about changes to close voting shown.  Since this change seems quite important (more so than burninating [sales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sales) quite honestly) I think this is exactly the sort of post that needs featuring - and yet somehow it's not there.

Is this a bug?

---

As reported in the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388322/3744182) this appears to be a caching issue.  Both Shog9's post (and this one?!) are now showing (while [burninate sales](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385971/should-we-burninate-the-sales-tag) is not) so the number of featured posts shown is clearly not limited to one.

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: It was showing up for a while, but it's not now.  I hereby declare that it's now an actual bug.

Comment: @Dragonrage - well that's one reason I checked in a completely separate browser.  Let's check a browser I **never** use... Nope, not there on IE.

Comment: @Dbc Dragonrage is referring to server side caching. The featured on Meta list is cached server side, so whatever browser you view it from will be the same. If the cache is lousy server side, all browsers will show the same bad cache

Comment: Repeat of this bug: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388272/7795130](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388272/7795130). Like I pointed out the first time, the "Featured tag has a shelf life" doesn't make sense since it was up for just a short time, so there's something wonky going on here.

Comment: Historically, "Featured on Meta" usually has a *significant* amount of delay relative to adding/removing the [meta-tag:featured] tag. This is usually explained as due to caching at various levels. The delays have commonly been indicated as up to several/many hours.

Comment: Well if the featured tab had a shelf life, then surely the old "burninate" from June would get kicked first?

Comment: I bumped the featured tag on the "burninate" post, to test the same bug report posted earlier.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that *one and only one* stackoverflow meta post can be featured at once, vs two from meta stack exchange?  And some not-necessarily-optimal arbitration algorithm decided picked the burninate post?

Comment: No, I've seen two posts there before.  See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), which has four featured posts.

Comment: @dWinder - I did see that, but until a few minutes ago, that one was tagged [tag:status-bydesign] with a comment about shelf lives, so I had inferred that newer featured posts were intended to bump older ones.  Which we're not seeing here.  So I thought another post might be appropriate.

Comment: Because the featured posts are covered by several systems of caching. This makes it difficult to mimic the old hot meta posts feature the site used to have. It can take many hours for the featured posts to update in the side bar and they do jostle around a bit for several hours. It's a low priority on putting dev resources into atm ***imo***.

Comment: @YvetteColomb - Now I'm totally confused.  You  just tagged this one as "status-bydesign" but the similar, previous one [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388272/featured-tag-not-working) just got untagged.  Also, I'm not sure this really should be "by design".  Maybe "status-declined"?  (Incidentally, how can a question be closed as a duplicate of another question that has no answers?  Is that something mods can do?)

Comment: @dbc I pinged a CM to clear this up. From my understanding this is typical behaviour - it's only being noticed now due to the focus on it since the removal of hot meta posts.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Did you add [meta-tag:featured] to this to test the bug? Or to bring light to it?

Comment: @JL2210 to add it to the featured posts, as it's relevant to the actual featured posts :)

Comment: why would people close this as a duplicate of an unanswered question? And while this is featured?

Comment: @YvetteColomb it's a normal ("default" if you wish) behavior when people prefer closing duplicates in favor of earlier question. Closing in opposite direction when there are better answers in later question (like it is I think in this case) is [known to be legitimate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252017/839601) but happens infrequently and many just aren't used to that

Comment: @YvetteColomb Well, it wasn't showing up until a few hours ago.

Comment: Can we just take a moment to appreciate the Win2K scroll bars? Respect!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*This answer is authored by Yvette and Shog (a community manager)*

Because the featured posts are covered by several systems of caching. This makes it difficult to mimic the old hot meta posts feature the site used to have.

You *may* be able to view this in action by hitting the API directly - here's a demo URL: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=featured&filter=!6JEVX4hBmKJVX&site=meta.stackoverflow

And here's the results I'm seeing for that right now:

[image: screenshot of API test utility showing only one featured post on MSO - the sales tag burnination]

As you can see, it *isn't* returning current results for the featured tag. If it returns those stale results when the bulletin refreshes (which it does roughly once per hour), then the bulletin will be stale for the next hour.

It can take many hours for the featured posts to update in the side bar and they do jostle around a bit for several hours.

It's a low priority on putting dev resources into atm ***imo***.

That being said, the slots are limited to 4 and include the blog posts.  If there are more featured posts than can fit, they will rotate in what is being shown as featured.  Thus it's not guaranteed that all featured posts will be shown concurrently.

Comment: Interesting, I just ran the query and got both of them: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=featured&site=meta.stackoverflow&filter=!6JEVX4hBmKJVX.  Still not showing up in the sidebar though.  Will check after dinner.

Comment: Interesting. I've also noticed recently that the number of items in the featured pane has jumped from as low as 1 to as high as 4 or 5. Is this related to the caching issues or is this some additional experimentation that the devs are doing in relation to the meta changes?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  One follow-up: of the three currently featured posts, two are showing in "Featured on Meta" - but one, the [burninate sales](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385971/should-we-burninate-the-sales-tag) post, is not.  Is there some logic limiting the number?

Comment: I feel like the easiest/obvious 5-minute solution is for the devs to not include the blog posts (or MSE posts) in the count...

Comment: @TylerH Especially since they are now farming content out to external contributors and not producing original content of their own.